# Calculate new column with growth rate based on two factors without splintering dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

Hej hej,

I would like to calculate growth rates, storing them in a new column of my data frame e.g. named growth.per.day. I am - as always - looking for a way that doesn't include hundreds and hundreds of lines of manually edited code.

I have six levels of algae and 25 levels of nutrients.
This means i have 150 "subgroups" for which i want to calculate the rates. Those subsets differ in length based on the individual algae.

So, basically:

Algae A ->

Nutrient (1) -> C.mikro.gr.L (Day 2) - C.mikro.gr.L (Day 1),C.mikro.gr.L (Day 3) - C.mikro.gr.L (Day 2) ... ;

Nutrient (2) -> C.mikro.gr.L (Day 2) - C.mikro.gr.L (Day 1),C.mikro.gr.L (Day 3) - C.mikro.gr.L (Day 2) ... etc.

I already split the data frame by algae

```
X <- split(data, data$ALGAE)
names(X) <- c("ANKI", "CHLAMY", "MIX_A", "MIX_B", "SCENE", "STAURA")
list2env(X, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

and i have also split those again, creating the aforementioned lovely 150 subsets. Then i applied

```
ratio1$growth.per.day <- c(NA,ratio1[2:nrow(ratio1), 16] - ratio1[1:(nrow(ratio1)-1), 16])
```

which is perfect and does what i want, BUT i would really very much appreciate a shorter, more elegant way without butchering my dataframe.

```
'data.frame':   3550 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ SAMPLE.ID   : Factor w/ 150 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ COMMUNITY   : chr  "com.1" "com.1" "com.1" "com.1" ...
 $ NUTRIENT    : Factor w/ 25 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ RATIO       : Factor w/ 23 levels "3.2","4","5.4",..: 11 9 6 4 1 14 10 8 5 2 ...
 $ PHOS        : Factor w/ 5 levels "0.09","0.195",..: 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ NIT         : Factor w/ 5 levels "1.5482","3.0964",..: 5 4 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 1 ...
 $ DATUM       : Factor w/ 35 levels "30.08.16","31.08.16",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ DAY         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TYPE        : chr  "mono" "mono" "mono" "mono" ...
 $ ALGAE       : Factor w/ 6 levels "ANK","CHLA","MIX A",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ MEAN        : num  864 868 882 873 872 ...
 $ GROW        : num  0.00116 0.00115 0.00113 0.00115 0.00115 ...
 $ FLUORO      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ MEAN.MQ     : num  0.964 0.969 0.985 0.975 0.973 ...
 $ GROW.MQ     : num  1.04 1.03 1.02 1.03 1.03 ...
 $ C.mikro.gr.L: num  -764 -913 -1394 -1085 -1039 ...
```

I hope this sufficiently describes the problem,

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is what you asked for:

```
df = data.frame(algae = sort(rep(LETTERS[1:6], 20)),
                nutrient = rep(letters[22:26], 24),
                day = rep(c(rep(1, 5), 
                        rep(2, 5),
                        rep(3, 5),
                        rep(4, 5)), 6),
                growth = runif(120, 30, 60))

library(dplyr)

df = df %>% group_by(algae, nutrient) %>% mutate(rate = c(NA, diff(growth, lag = 1)))
```

And there the table for alga A and nutrient v:

```
   algae nutrient   day   growth      rate
  <fctr>   <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1      A        v     1 48.68547        NA
2      A        v     2 55.63570  6.950232
3      A        v     3 53.28569 -2.350013
4      A        v     4 44.83022 -8.455465
```

Comment: That is amazing :) thank you so much! its probably not much but i find it extremely cool

Comment: i cant i am sorry, i already tried but my reputation is tooo low -.-